# Ci sono altre parole che possono sostituire l'espressione "Vado punto e a capo"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella canzone *Sei nell'anima* di Gianna Nannini c'è l'espressione "Vado punto e a capo"

> Vado punto e a capo così
> Spegnerò le luci
> E da qui sparirai
> Pochi attimi

Ci sono altre parole che possono sostituire l'espressione "Vado punto e a capo"?

Cosa significa l'espressione in questo contesto?